# mysql - The target table of the UPDATE is not updatable using trigger

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, triggers

update 2nd and 3rd row  table after update 1st the row on same table
store procedure or trigger after update  in table (using mysql)

```
id |Is_executed | Is_Ready  
1  | 0          |  
2  |            | 0  
3  |            | 0
```

if i update is_executed to '1' of  id is 1 then i want following row update

```
id |Is_executed | Is_Ready  
1  | 1          |  
2  |            | 1  
3  |            | 1
```

using trigger or store procedure

Comment: I don't know about others, but I don't understand what exactly is your question. Please clarify.

Comment: What is your question? You fail to describe properly the problem you have and don't even ask a question.

Answer (score 0):

Your desired business logic isn't entirely clear from your question, but it sounds like you want a trigger along the following lines:

```
DELIMITER ;;

CREATE TRIGGER my_trigger AFTER UPDATE ON my_table FOR EACH ROW
  IF NEW.id = 1 AND OLD.Is_executed = 0 AND NEW.Is_executed = 1 THEN
    UPDATE my_table SET Is_Ready = 1 WHERE id IN (2,3);
  END IF
;;

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: not working but logic is correct, trigger not allowed this one how this converted into stored-procedures. trigger has limitation

Comment: @saurabhagrawal: What does "not working" mean in this context? Also, you can create a stored procedure, please read the documentation to learn more about that.

Comment: how to convert below  trigger query  to store procedure  

 CREATE TRIGGER my_trigger AFTER UPDATE ON orderbook FOR EACH ROW  
BEGIN  
  IF NEW.cob_OrderSeq = 'MAIN' AND NEW.cob_Is_Executed = 1 THEN  
    UPDATE orderbook SET cob_is_Ready = 1 WHERE cob_OrderSeq IN ('SL','PB');  
  END IF;  
END;  
 

thank you in advanced..